# Python zipfile module: difference between zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED and zipfile.ZIP_STORED

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I have difficulty understanding the difference between zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED and zipfile.ZIP_STORED compression modes of the zipfile module.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`ZIP_DEFLATED` correspond to an archive member (a file inside the archive) which is compressed (or deflated). `ZIP_STORED` correspond to an archive member which is simply stored, without being compressed, quite the same as an archive member inside a `tar` file.